# How to collaborate with a translation pakage for the control panel?

Tags: magento2, localisation

I'd like to know how could I translate the *control panel* for Magento 2.x, I've seen that the packages are created, but empty, how could I collaborate in order to translate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translations for Magento2 are crowdsourced at https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2 (official translations project for Magento 2) and everybody can participate.

Comment: Thanks, does it apply for Magento 1? also, every version of magento 1 shares the same translations? I mean magento 1.7 and magento 1.9 would work with the same translation package? check this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/94422/34342

Comment: There's no such project for Magento 1. The translation packages need updates for each version because there were always new translations. The official translation packages were translated by translation bureaus and mostly of low quality, so if there's an unofficial package by the community for your language, it's probably better.

Comment: Oh, I see, what could I do in order to make a tranlation module for 1.9.2.2?

Comment: Basically copy app/locale/en_US to app/locale/xx_XX and change all the CSV and HTML files